# SQL Server : very rare Transaction Commit Issue

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, transactions

I am developing a web application with ASP.NET 4.0 with VB.NET as codebehind.
I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 as backend.

I am experiencing very rare problem on a page in my project.

I am entering around two hundred data in textboxes in Telerik Radgrid.

All these information is going to be saved in the database table. When Its saved for the first time, it is working fine and saved in the same order as it is displayed in the grid.

But when I try to update it sometime later, the last row of the grid, it is saved sometimes(not every time) second last in the table. I don't know why and this is my problem I want answer for.

I want the data to stored exactly in the same order as displayed in the grid.

But on update, I find problem with this last row of grid, which is saved second last in table when I commit transaction, it should be saved last.

I am providing VB.NET code below.

```
Protected Sub SaveBothGridData()
    Dim sb1 As New StringBuilder
    Dim tran1 As SqlTransaction
    Dim tran2 As SqlTransaction
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DPMTConnectionString").ConnectionString)
    Try
        'get the existing datatable
        Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0
        If ViewState("DT_SR1_section1") IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim dtCurrentTable1 As DataTable = DirectCast(ViewState("DT_SR1_section1"), DataTable)

            If dtCurrentTable1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To dtCurrentTable1.Rows.Count - 1
                    Dim box1 As TextBox = DirectCast(RadGrid1.Items(rowIndex).FindControl("TextBox1"), TextBox)
                    Dim box2 As TextBox = DirectCast(RadGrid1.Items(rowIndex).FindControl("TextBox2"), TextBox)
                    Dim box3 As TextBox = DirectCast(RadGrid1.Items(rowIndex).FindControl("TextBox3"), TextBox)
                    Dim box4 As TextBox = DirectCast(RadGrid1.Items(rowIndex).FindControl("TextBox4"), TextBox)
                    Dim box5 As TextBox = DirectCast(RadGrid1.Items(rowIndex).FindControl("TextBox5"), TextBox)
                    Dim box6 As TextBox = DirectCast(RadGrid1.Items(rowIndex).FindControl("TextBox6"), TextBox)
                    Dim box7 As TextBox = DirectCast(RadGrid1.Items(rowIndex).FindControl("TextBox7"), TextBox)
                    Dim box8 As TextBox = DirectCast(RadGrid1.Items(rowIndex).FindControl("TextBox8"), TextBox)
                    Dim box9 As TextBox = DirectCast(RadGrid1.Items(rowIndex).FindControl("TextBox9"), TextBox)
                    Dim box10 As TextBox = DirectCast(RadGrid1.Items(rowIndex).FindControl("TextBox10"), TextBox)
                    Dim box11 As TextBox = DirectCast(RadGrid1.Items(rowIndex).FindControl("TextBox11"), TextBox)
                    Dim box12 As TextBox = DirectCast(RadGrid1.Items(rowIndex).FindControl("TextBox12"), TextBox)
                    Dim box13 As TextBox = DirectCast(RadGrid1.Items(rowIndex).FindControl("TextBox13"), TextBox)
                    Dim box14 As TextBox = DirectCast(RadGrid1.Items(rowIndex).FindControl("TextBox14"), TextBox)


                    dtCurrentTable1.Rows(i)("CAT") = box1.Text
                    dtCurrentTable1.Rows(i)("PTTL") = box2.Text
                    dtCurrentTable1.Rows(i)("C1") = box3.Text
                    dtCurrentTable1.Rows(i)("C2") = box4.Text
                    dtCurrentTable1.Rows(i)("C3") = box5.Text
                    dtCurrentTable1.Rows(i)("C4") = box6.Text
                    dtCurrentTable1.Rows(i)("C5") = box7.Text
                    dtCurrentTable1.Rows(i)("C6") = box8.Text
                    dtCurrentTable1.Rows(i)("C7") = box9.Text
                    dtCurrentTable1.Rows(i)("C8") = box10.Text
                    dtCurrentTable1.Rows(i)("C9") = box11.Text
                    dtCurrentTable1.Rows(i)("C10") = box12.Text
                    dtCurrentTable1.Rows(i)("CTTL") = box13.Text
                    dtCurrentTable1.Rows(i)("DIFF") = box14.Text
                    rowIndex += 1
                    sb1.Append(box1.Text & " " & box2.Text & " " & box3.Text & " " & box4.Text & " " & box5.Text & " " & box6.Text & " " & box7.Text & " " & box8.Text & " " & box9.Text & " " & box10.Text & " " & box11.Text & " " & box12.Text & " " & box13.Text & " " & box14.Text & " " & Now.ToString & vbCrLf)
                Next
            End If

            'save datatable to database
            Dim shadingno As Integer = 0
            shadingno = Me.hdnShadingNo_section1.Value

            cn.Open()
            tran1 = cn.BeginTransaction
            Dim mode As String = String.Empty
            If Not Request.QueryString("shadingno") Is Nothing Then
                Dim delcmd As New SqlCommand
                delcmd.Connection = cn
                delcmd.Transaction = tran1
                delcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                delcmd.CommandText = "sp_delete_shading_return_1_entry"
                delcmd.Parameters.Add("@shadingno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Request.QueryString("shadingno")
                delcmd.Parameters.Add("@section", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "section1"
                delcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End If

            'If Not Request.QueryString("shadingno") Is Nothing Then
            '    Dim obj As New db
            '    Dim str As String = "delete from shading_return_entry_general where shadingno=" & Request.QueryString("shadingno")
            '    str = str & ";delete from shading_return_entry_details where shadingno=" & Request.QueryString("shadingno")
            '    obj.insertAll(str)
            '    obj = Nothing
            'End If
            'Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand
            'cmd1.Transaction = tran
            'cmd1.Connection = cn
            'cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            'cmd1.CommandText = "sp_add_update_delete_shading_return_entry_general"
            'cmd1.Parameters.Add("@mode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "ADD"
            'cmd1.Parameters.Add("@srno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0
            'cmd1.Parameters.Add("@shadingno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = shadingno
            'cmd1.Parameters.Add("@entrytimestamp", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Now
            'cmd1.Parameters.Add("@approvalstatus", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "NOT APPROVED"
            'cmd1.Parameters.Add("@approvaltimestamp", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.Null
            'cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand
            cmd2.Transaction = tran1
            cmd2.Connection = cn
            cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd2.CommandText = "sp_add_update_delete_shading_return_1_heading_details"
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@mode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "ADD"
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@shadingno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = shadingno
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@section", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "section1"
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@col1heading", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = UCase(Me.hdnCol1Heading_section1.Value)
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@col2heading", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = UCase(Me.hdnCol2Heading_section1.Value)
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@col3heading", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = UCase(Me.hdnCol3Heading_section1.Value)
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@col4heading", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = UCase(Me.hdnCol4Heading_section1.Value)
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@col5heading", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = UCase(Me.hdnCol5Heading_section1.Value)
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@col6heading", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = UCase(Me.hdnCol6Heading_section1.Value)
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@col7heading", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = UCase(Me.hdnCol7Heading_section1.Value)
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@col8heading", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = UCase(Me.hdnCol8Heading_section1.Value)
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@col9heading", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = UCase(Me.hdnCol9Heading_section1.Value)
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@col10heading", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = UCase(Me.hdnCol10Heading_section1.Value)
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Dim sw As StreamWriter = IO.File.CreateText(Server.MapPath("../ADMIN/") & Now.Day & Now.Month & Now.Year & Now.Hour & Now.Minute & Now.Second & ".txt")
            sw.Write(sb1.ToString)
            sw.Flush()
            sw.Close()

            For i = 0 To dtCurrentTable1.Rows.Count - 1
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
                cmd.Transaction = tran1
                cmd.Connection = cn
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                cmd.CommandText = "sp_add_update_delete_shading_return_1_entry_details"
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@mode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "ADD"
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@shadingno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = shadingno
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@section", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "section1"
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@cat", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = dtCurrentTable1.Rows(i).Item(0)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@pttl", SqlDbType.Float).Value = dtCurrentTable1.Rows(i).Item(1)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@col1", SqlDbType.Float).Value = dtCurrentTable1.Rows(i).Item(2)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@col2", SqlDbType.Float).Value = dtCurrentTable1.Rows(i).Item(3)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@col3", SqlDbType.Float).Value = dtCurrentTable1.Rows(i).Item(4)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@col4", SqlDbType.Float).Value = dtCurrentTable1.Rows(i).Item(5)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@col5", SqlDbType.Float).Value = dtCurrentTable1.Rows(i).Item(6)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@col6", SqlDbType.Float).Value = dtCurrentTable1.Rows(i).Item(7)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@col7", SqlDbType.Float).Value = dtCurrentTable1.Rows(i).Item(8)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@col8", SqlDbType.Float).Value = dtCurrentTable1.Rows(i).Item(9)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@col9", SqlDbType.Float).Value = dtCurrentTable1.Rows(i).Item(10)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@col10", SqlDbType.Float).Value = dtCurrentTable1.Rows(i).Item(11)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@cttl", SqlDbType.Float).Value = dtCurrentTable1.Rows(i).Item(12)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@diff", SqlDbType.Float).Value = dtCurrentTable1.Rows(i).Item(13)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next
            tran1.Commit()

            'Dim eventMsg As String = "Shading Return entry section1 with shading no " & shadingno & " created"
            'Dim obj1 As New com.hemalrathod.dpmt.DatabaseHandling
            'obj1.SaveToUserEventLog(Request.Cookies.Item("loginname").Value, "Shading return entry 1 create", eventMsg, Now, Request.Cookies.Item("clientipaddress").Value)
            'obj1 = Nothing
            'Response.Redirect("Shading_View.aspx")
        Else
            Response.Write("ViewState is null")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex.Message)
    Finally
        cn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

In the above code, I am creating a transaction to save the data, when updating, I first delete the original data and then saving the new one.

Problem is with only first transaction 'tran1'. I haven't found any problem with 'tran2'.

I think problem is with committing transaction. When its committed, somehow, the last row of grid, is saved second last in the table.

Following is the SQL Server procedure I used

Procedure for deleting the existing data before entering new data

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_delete_shading_return_1_entry]
(
@shadingno int,
@section nvarchar(50)
)
as
delete from shading_return_1_heading_details 
    where shadingno = @shadingno and section = @section

delete from shading_return_1_entry_details 
    where shadingno = @shadingno and section = @section

delete from shading_return_entry_general 
    where shadingno = @shadingno
```

Procedure for entering new heading data(this is not creating any problem)

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_add_update_delete_shading_return_1_heading_details]
(
@mode nvarchar(50),
@shadingno int,
@section nvarchar(50),
@col1heading nvarchar(50),
@col2heading nvarchar(50),
@col3heading nvarchar(50),
@col4heading nvarchar(50),
@col5heading nvarchar(50),
@col6heading nvarchar(50),
@col7heading nvarchar(50),
@col8heading nvarchar(50),
@col9heading nvarchar(50),
@col10heading nvarchar(50)
)
as
if @mode='ADD'
begin
    insert into shading_return_1_heading_details values(@shadingno, @section, @col1heading, @col2heading, @col3heading, @col4heading, @col5heading, @col6heading, @col7heading, @col8heading, @col9heading, @col10heading)
end
```

Procedure to store data from radgrid to the table(THIS IS ACTUALLY WHERE ERROR MIGHT BE)

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_add_update_delete_shading_return_1_entry_details]
(
@mode nvarchar(50),
@shadingno int,
@section nvarchar(50),
@cat nvarchar(50),
@pttl float,
@col1 float,
@col2 float,
@col3 float,
@col4 float,
@col5 float,
@col6 float,
@col7 float,
@col8 float,
@col9 float,
@col10 float,
@cttl float,
@diff float
)
as
if @mode='ADD'
begin
    insert into shading_return_1_entry_details 
            values(@shadingno, @section, @cat, @pttl, @col1, @col2, @col3, @col4, @col5, @col6, @col7, @col8, @col9, @col10, @cttl, @diff)

end
```

After this, as per my VB.NET code, I am committing 'tran1' transaction, and then problem occurs sometimes not often.

In short, I want all rows in radgrid to be stored exactly in the same order, but after committing transaction, sometimes, the last row of grid, is stored second last in the table.

How can I solve this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should provide as little code as possible to demonstrate your problem if you expect people to help you. No one is likely to sift through hundreds of lines of code.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the suggestion, I would keep this in mind, But I thought this would help to understand my problem.

Comment: Yes, it will, just keep it to essential code to reproduce the problem. Too much code is just as bad as too little code - too little and your problem cannot be understood; too much and people won't read through it.